# Can't create virtualenv with jython 2.7b2 as an interpreter

Tags: python, virtualenv, jython, pyro

I want to execute some Java code from Python so I've decided to install standard python interpreter, jython and join them together using pyro4. Pyro4 requires python > 2.5 so I choose to use jython 2.7b. Here are steps I made to make this happen:

```
wget -i jython-installer-2.7-b2.jar http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/python/jython-installer/2.7-b1/jython-installer-2.7-b2.jar
java -jar jython-installer-2.7-b2.jar
jython2.7b2/bin/virtualenv-2.7 oscar
```

And this is what I'm getting back:

```
Cannot find file /home/mnowotka/jython2.7b2/Include (bad symlink)
New jython executable in oscar/bin/jython
Installing setuptools.................
  Complete output from command /home/mnowotka/oscar/bin/jython -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])

" /home/mnowotka/jytho...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg:
  Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 278, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 210, in main
  File "<string>", line 161, in download_setuptools
  File "/home/mnowotka/jython2.7b2/Lib/socket.py", line 1651, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(recv_size)
  File "/home/mnowotka/jython2.7b2/Lib/httplib.py", line 567, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/home/mnowotka/jython2.7b2/Lib/socket.py", line 1669, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(recv_size)
  File "/home/mnowotka/jython2.7b2/Lib/socket.py", line 174, in handle_exception
    raise _map_exception(jlx)
socket.error: [Errno 32] Socket closed
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jython2.7b2/bin/virtualenv-2.7", line 3, in <module>
    virtualenv.main()
  File "/home/mnowotka/jython2.7b2/Lib/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 970, in main
    create_environment(home_dir,
  File "/home/mnowotka/jython2.7b2/Lib/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1090, in create_environment
    install_setuptools(py_executable, unzip=unzip_setuptools,
  File "/home/mnowotka/jython2.7b2/Lib/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 610, in install_setuptools
    _install_req(py_executable, unzip,
  File "/home/mnowotka/jython2.7b2/Lib/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 579, in _install_req
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False,
  File "/home/mnowotka/jython2.7b2/Lib/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1055, in call_subprocess
    raise OSError(
OSError: Command /home/mnowotka/oscar/bin/jython -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])
```

Does it mean that jython 2.7b2 is not quite ready yet or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Use this ez_setup.py to install setuptools:

[added setuptools-egg and md5](http://pastebin.com/xwHTdCVJ)

Comment: And what is different between this and the method used by the asker? I.e. Why does this work?

Comment: The asker wanted to try to setup this "oscar", which tried to bootstrap setuptools for its use. What was missing was the egg-file entry and the checksum in this file, I did that and uploaded it for him. So it is my link, and I don't gona change it. And before voting me down, go home and cry that you didn't come to this answer. Bye!

Comment: @noragen - Thank you for your answer any help is always welcome. I will definitely give it a try and report back with results. I'm sorry for people voting down your answer without actually trying it. To keep balance you have +1 in advance from me.

Comment: This link now 404s, rendering this answer completely unusable.

Comment: The new link takes me to a page for which Firefox says "This Connection is Untrusted".

Comment: I'm sorry, this is however lays not in my decision. However this is no confidential data. You can trust and accept.

Comment: Link fixed again and added Mirror.